# Duda, ¿Como puedo hacer las clases en este ejercicio?

Tags: java

Hola hasta ahora no me había surgido ninguna duda, pero este ejercicio mas que tener dudas fue que se me ocurrieron muchas formas de resolverlo, aquí pongo la mas cercana de las que se me ocurrieron.

```
  package mom;

  import java.io.BufferedReader;  
  import java.io.IOException;  
  import java.io.InputStreamReader;  
  import java.util.Scanner;

public class Mom {

public static void main(String[] args) throws NumberFormatException, IOException {
    BufferedReader bufEntrada = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)); 
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    int capacidad1 = 5000;
    int capacidad2 = 5000;
    int capacidad3 = 5000;
    int vaciar = 0;
    int vasochico = 300;
    int vasomediano = 400;
    int vasogrande = 500;
    int opc=0;
    int servir =0;
    int contenido=0;
    int contenido1 = 0;
    int contenido2 = 0;
    int dispensador=0;
    int vaso=0;
    int nivel=0;

    while ((opc!=5)){
      System.out.println("1.- llenar la maquina");
      System.out.println("2.- servir vasos");
      System.out.println("3.- vaciar dispensador");
      System.out.println("4.- mostrar nivel");
      System.out.println("5.- salir");
      opc = in.nextInt();

      if((opc==1)){
          System.out.println("Seleccione el dispensador");
              System.out.println("1.- dispensador 1");
              System.out.println("2.- dispensador 2");
              System.out.println("3.- dispensador 3");
              dispensador = Integer.parseInt(bufEntrada.readLine());
          switch(dispensador){
              case 1:
                  capacidad1 = 5000;
                  break;
              case 2:
                  capacidad2 = 5000;
                  break;
              case 3: 
                  capacidad3 = 5000;
                  break;
          }
      }


      if(opc==2){
               System.out.println("Seleccione el tipo de vaso");
               System.out.println("1.- chico");
               System.out.println("2.- mediano");
               System.out.println("3.- grande");
               vaso = in.nextInt();
               if(vaso==1){
                   vasochico = 300;
                   contenido = capacidad1 - vasochico;
               }
               if(vaso==2){
                   vasomediano = 400;
                   contenido1 = capacidad2 - vasomediano;
               }
               if(vaso==3){
                   vasogrande = 500;
                   contenido2 = capacidad3 - vasogrande;
               }
           }


      if(opc==3){
               System.out.println("Seleccioe el dispensador que se vaciara");
               System.out.println("1.- bebida 1");
               System.out.println("2.- bebida 2");
               System.out.println("3.- bebida 3");
    }



      if(opc==4){
          System.out.println("El nivel de los dispensadores es:");
          System.out.println("el nivel del dispensador 1 es:"+contenido);
          System.out.println("el nivel del dispenador 2 es:"+contenido1);
          System.out.println("el nivel del dispensador 3 es:"+contenido2);     
}
}
}
}
```

también estuve intentando la posibilidad de hacerlo en dos clases, pero no fui capaz de sacar nada en claro.
Ya estoy comenzando a programar en java y el profesor como no explica muy bien que digamos y solo hemos hecho un solo ejercicio pues a mi no me quedo claro como se programa
también no explica casi nada de la clases y como me acaba de decir a ultimo momento que eran necesarias y pues me quede programando así pero no logre encontrar una manera de hacer que tenga clases

Comment: Iba a escribir una respuesta, pero casi que sin contenido, porque de hacerlo resuelvo tu ejercicio.. tips.. Si es un ejercicio sobre 3 dispensadores... seguro, habra una clase dispensador ;). y esa clase sabe cuanto tiene, cuantos vasos tiene, se sabe llenar y se sabe vaciar.. empeza por ahi...

Comment: Bien eso es un comienzo no busco que lo hagan solo busco una manera de hacer las clases gracias por el aporte lo tomare en cuenta